# POST request 404 (Not Found) with angular.js and ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I'm trying to send a request to my ExpressJS server using AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app').controller('contactCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.envoyer = function(nom, organisation, courriel, telephone, message){
        $http.post('/contact', {nom:nom, organisation:organisation, courriel:courriel, telephone:telephone, message:message}).then(function(error, response){
            if(response.data.success){
                console.log('sent!');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the code from the server:

```
var mailer = require('nodemailer');

var EMAIL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = 'aaa@gmail.com';
var EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD = 'aaa';

var smtpTransport = mailer.createTransport({
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: EMAIL_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
        pass: EMAIL_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD
    }
});

app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next){
        var success = true;
        var mailOptions = {
            to: 'azez@email.com',
            subject: 'qsdxwccvfd',
            html: 'sqdqsdq'
        };

        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, res){
            if(error){
                console.log('[ERROR] Message NOT sent: ', error);
                success = false;
            } else {
                console.log('[INFO] Message sent: ' + res.message);
            }
            next(error, success);
        });
});
```

After the server performs the request, I get this error message on the client side:

```
POST http://localhost:3002/contact 404 (Not Found) angular.js:8495
(anonymous function) angular.js:8495
sendReq angular.js:8291
$http.serverRequest angular.js:8025
wrappedCallback angular.js:11498
wrappedCallback angular.js:11498
(anonymous function) angular.js:11584
Scope.$eval angular.js:12608
Scope.$digest angular.js:12420
Scope.$apply angular.js:12712
(anonymous function) angular.js:18980
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:4409
elemData.handle
```

I think that it's coming from the fourth line of the AngularJS code, but I wasn't able to find how to fix it. How can I fix that, please?

Comment: The server is indicating that there is no resource at ``http://localhost:3002/contact``. Were you expecting something to be there? What code is providing the implementation of that endpoint?

Comment: Your middleware for ``/contact`` doesn't return a response. Assuming that's the entire server code (and there isn't some later middleware handling it) then the call to ``next`` will return your 404. If you'd like an example of returning JSON data for the client to parse then let me know and I can write one up, assuming that's an ``express`` app.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, in fact, i'm trying to display a toastr notification in the client side when the email sent works, how do I to set a success attribute at the response and to display a that toastr notification in the other side ?

Comment: @MartinAtkins, you're right, I'm using expressjs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send a successful response to the browser, the call to `next` at the end of your middleware should be replaced with something like this:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); // tell Angular that this is JSON
res.send(JSON.stringify({success: success}));
```

These lines tell express to return a response marked as a success, with a body that is in JSON format with an object that only has the "success" property.

However, in order for this to work you will need to rename the parameter you used in the callback for `smtpTransport.sendMail` since you called that `res` and so it is currently hiding the `res` object from the middleware. So change the header of that function to something like this:

```
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, mailRes){
```

...and then of course you must change the log line that follows to use `mailRes` instead of `res`.

Comment: I'm getting this error message : `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
`

Comment: Did you update the ``mailRes`` parameter as I indicated? I'd expect that error if ``res`` were still the mail-sending result rather than the Express response object.

Comment: Can you add ``console.log(res)`` just before the ``res.set`` call, so we can see what exactly that object is here? Looks like somehow it's not the Express response object.

Comment: I've got as response `{ accepted: [ 'aaa@gmail.com' ],
  rejected: [],
  response: '250 2.0.0 OK 1406434616 ed15sm14788940wic.9 - gsmtp',
  envelope: { from: false, to: [ 'aaa@gmail.com' ] },
  messageId: '1406434615279-ca07793a-8e5861d7-da24b177@localhost' }
`

Comment: That sure looks like a response from ``smtpTransport.sendMail`` to me. Please make sure the variable name ``res`` is *only* used in the line ``app.post('/contact', function(req, res, next){`` and in the lines I gave in my response. That variable name should not be used anywhere else in the function.

Comment: It's now working, but I still need to catch that sent params from the other client side.

Comment: I think you're now asking about how to access the parameters passed from Angular on the server? If so, I think that's a separate question and so better to open a new question rather than continuing this discussion here. I'm happy to answer your new question if you make a new question page for it and post a link to it here.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the `succes` param from the client side !

Comment: I expected that to work now. If not, I suggest to ``console.log(response.data)`` in your callback, before your ``if`` statement, and see what is being returned. It ought to be an object with a ``success`` property, but maybe the property is ``false`` if it's not actually working.

Comment: I'm getting this, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: And using `console.log(response)` I get `undefined` as result

Comment: Oh, I see your problem now. The ``then`` callback does not take an extra ``error`` parameter. It should just be ``.then(function (response) {``.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I really need to deepen my knowledge on javascript

Comment: No worries... keep trying things and asking questions!

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine dear. You have given same name to the smtpTransport response as **"res"**, just change it. it will work fine. for snnipet please refer to below given example.

```
app.post('/contact', function (req, res, next) {
    var success = true;
    var mailOptions = {
        to: 'deepak.m.shrma@email.com',
        subject: 'hey',
        html: 'hello'
    };
    smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('[ERROR] Message NOT sent: ', error);
            success = false;
            res.send(error)
        } else {
            console.log('[INFO] Message sent: ' + result);
        }
        res.send(result)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with express 4.0. I fixed it by reinstalling body-parser:

```
npm install body-parser
```

Then doing:

```
git add -A
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got also same problem. Even Database inserted and there is no error in my IDE console, where i run my local, comes on browser 404. Adding

```
res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successful' });
```

to controller response solved my problem. Info: PATCH works fine without returning Success, but POST not.